# How does last.fm free music player retrieve the tracks from last.fm server?

Tags: last.fm, streaming

Isn't it restricted?

I mean even the last.fm radio is not gratis let alone streaming tracks or maybe it is using last.fm just for the track names and streaming them from other services like Grooveshark?

[last.fm free music player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbncpldmanoknoahidbgmkgobgmhnafh)

Comment: Last.fm is free in the United States.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of tracks which can be retrieved from last.fm with no restrictions on how many times they can be listened to, or in which territories they may be streamed. There are some which do, but this is handled serverside, so the client doesn't have any say in it.

Your question is a bit unclear -- there are plenty of free tracks on last.fm, and the service is free. So to answer your query -- no, it is not restricted in a lot of cases, and when it is, the client is blocked.

Comment: that plugin can play all songs not only free ones.

Comment: That's not correct. The plugin can play extended versions which are capped on site/when listened to over *n* times, it follows the same limits as the official client.